# Sympy mechanics, plotting vectors and reference frames in 2-space

Tags: python, simulation, physics, sympy

In summary, I'd like to plot a model I made using sympy.

I'm currently trying to animate the evolution of a bicycle model along a curve in 2-space.

So far I have three matplotlib patches that represent the body and two tires of the bicycle, as well as the dynamic equations created with the sympy mechanics module.

I'm currently able to numerically integrate the equations using KanesMethod, however plotting these objects is a different challenge.

This is what I've come up with so far, and I feel like there has to be a better way to go about all this.

```
position_vector.subs(...).to_matrix(inertial_reference_frame)
```

Then I'd have to plot each of the two coordinates over time.

I don't even know where to start with plotting reference frames. I guess I'd somehow turn the reference frame into a set of 3 unit vectors, substitute numerical values, and plot them using matplotlib's quiver command.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stackoverflow! I recommend you take the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)
to know your way arround here (and earn your first badge also ;) ). Also to improve the chances of getting useful answers
please check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and also how to create [Complete, Minimal, and Verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).